# How to convert a TChain to an array in root_numpy?

Tags: rootpy

What is the best way to convert a TChain to an array in root_numpy?
The function tree2array only works with trees, and it would be nice to not have to manually loop over every file and make a tree for each separate file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspect nowadays [uproot] is the prefered for such a task. though no idea if there's chain support. (also, i assume using the `hadd` command and merging the files prior to conversion is undesirable in your case).